# Which Champions specialize in burst damage and high mobility?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm having trouble with having high mobility and yet dealing enough damage to matter in team fights. What is a good strategy, champion or build order that would allow me to be as mobile as I can while still having high enough damage to carry the game?

Could you classify them by lane as well?

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.nerfplz.com/2016/02/2016-champion-tier-list-solo-queue_14.html

Comment: Don't get why this is opinion based, do these people not play league? A mobile champion is pretty obvious it's not an opinion.

Comment: Yeah, some times happen. I think the question is ok, and will try to give an answer if reopenned

Comment: For those wondering why this question was closed has opinion based it's because  a champion cannot be considered mobile just for these types of spells, let's think about jinx for example, she is considered immobile, but when she gets a kills or assist she is suddenly faster than Rammus, so that is why this question was closed has opinion based

Comment: But if you manage to get this question reopenned i will be glad to provide you with a list of all the "mobile" champions, and even how to play agaisnt them if you want

Comment: Better reason to close would have been the question being too broad, since it is not defining the scope narrowly enough to give a concise, accurate answer. All answers to this question would be patch-based as well.

Comment: Now it's too broad. What are you trying to do? Don't tell us what you want the solution to be, tell us what problem you're trying to solve. I think there might be something here, but right now, there's nothing here suited to Arqade.

Comment: I think this title pins down the core question. Feel free to rollback the edit if it doesn't capture your intent. @Frank, does the title make it clear that this is not opinion-based?

Comment: I also applied some changes without changing the intent (hopefully).  Could someone clarify this sentence "Fizz is also an example, as he has his E."  What is E?  May be worth making that clearer in the question (unless is it completely obvious in the context of the game).

Comment: @Magmagod that's just not true. That's like saying buying Mobility Boots makes everyone mobile. Except in combat. There's some truth to that (they do get a tad more mobile), but it doesn't define mobility.

Comment: @Charkz several LoL questions are closed because people who have no (aparant) expertise in LoL are allowed to vote to close, and don't even give a chance for the OP or other people to actually edit / answer or even explain why it is not offtopic. This question in fact is very on topic, as burst damage and mobility is actually what defines an assassin, which then would be which champions are able to be morphed into assassins.

Comment: @Oak Yes, I agree that there is a valid question here, but the way it was originally written (especially the original title), I find it very understandable why people voted to close it as opinion based. For awareness, there is [a meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11332/league-of-legends-questions-separating-opinion-from-meta-strategy-and-other-f) about this question being put on hold.

Comment: The latest edit doesn't help any, I'm afraid. It's still wanting a lost of champions that meet specific criteria. Lists, while they can be on-topic, generally point at an underlying issue. Tell what what problem you're trying to solve. Not what you want, but the issue you're trying to fix.

Comment: What Frank is trying to say is your question just needs reworded to an actual question instead of you just wanting a list. Your question could be something like, "I'm having trouble with having high mobility and yet dealing enough damage to matter in team fights. What is a good strategy, champion or build order that would allow me to be as mobile as I can while still having high enough damage to carry the game?"

Comment: Needing a short list of champions that possess certain attributes is actually perfectly reasonable for this game. With the quantity of bans, and amount of different positions available it's reasonable to expect to need 4 to 6 different champions that fulfill the same basic niche.

Comment: @Frank I know that asking for lists of **games** is off-topic, but asking for lists of champions/characters/items/etc. seems like it's on-topic and acceptable, to me at least. Even a bunch of the 'Related' questions are asking for lists: `Which champions can jungle effectively in League of Legends?`, `Which champions have pets?`. Can't the problem trying to be solved be "I like these high-mobility, burst damage characters. What other characters fit that criteria, since I could target using them?

Comment: @ChaseC None of the questions you listed even remotely try to touch the subject of this question, with the exception of "What is a good champion that would allow me to be as mobile as I can while still having high enough damage to carry the game?" Which can be boiled down to, "Which Champion(s) specialize(s) in burst damage and high mobility?" There's a certain playstyle that inherently exists within certain champions' kits. This playstyle can be low mobility, high damage. It could even be low damage, high impact (cc, etc).

Comment: Fortunately, those features are described by just one word in League of Legends: Assassin. That's the real answer here, if I were allowed to write one. Try out other assassin class champions, the class of champions includes such champions as Zed, Kha'Zix, and LeBlanc. Was that so darn hard? No. Is it even remotely opinion-based? Nope.

Comment: And if we really wanted to get specific, I could even talk about the one or two exceptions there are, like Veigar, who deals really high damage, but primarily to mages and has very low mobility to compensate for the especially high damage output.

Comment: @camelCase It is completely obvious to someone who plays League what Fizz's E ability is. It is Playful/Trickster. It's a two-part spell that makes him untargetable  for the first part of the spell and allows him to hop a short distance for the second part, dealing magic damage in an area around the spot that he lands. The ability can traverse walls if used properly.

Comment: Is "bursty" a defined word in LoL? That sound super opinion-based to my ears, not being a regular LoL player.

Comment: @DCShannon http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_terminology#B

Comment: Also, for anyone still interested in this conversation, here's a link describing Assassins in League: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Assassin_champion

Comment: the op is looking for a for champions in lol that fulfill 2 conditions. the champion must be a burst based kit, and have abilities that permit fast and reliable positioning and reposition.
Well i don't find the question too broad and would vote to reopen this question because i find it easy to answer. there are only a bunch of champions that fit into the two conditions

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [Assassins](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Assassin_champion). Typically assassins have high burst and high mobility. Good examples are Kha'Zix and Zed.

Typically assassins are played in the mid or top lane, although some can/should jungle. [Champion.gg](http://champion.gg/) is a great resource for finding out where each champion is typically played.

There are some non-assassin's that fulfill your requirements, but I don't think that they're precisely what you're looking for, given the examples that you provided.

Answer (score 4):

I will list champions that fulfill both conditions, mobility and burst but i will differentiate them more by mobility and damage type than lane or "class" (ADC, bruiser, support, mage, assasin) because many of these champions can fill more than one lane.

What I define as a burst character : Champion who can do mayor damage in a really short period of time, can at least do 70% of max health in damage in that short time.

Some champion have burst patterns but they need more time tan what the op expects, Zilean,Poppy,Darius,Garen are characters that normaly have a burst pattern but need more time or preparation to archive what others do in mere seconds

What I define as a character with mobility: Champion with low cooldown skills that permits him to traverse some distances.

Characters like Teemo and Miss Fortune altough they can speed up to try outrun their pursuers they are considered pretty inmobile champions. having the capacity to run fast is not the same that having the capacity to leap or teleport on an enemy or away, with these teleport or leaps being nearly instant and covering a distance that would require more time with only movement speed

The champions I list can reliably kill squishy or weakened champions with only 1 spell rotation or combo in 3 seconds or less.

### Multipurpose and high mobility:

Those are champions that can use their mobility spells to bypass obstacles in any direction and have a relative short cooldown.

**AD:**

- *Jarvan IV*: Mobility through EQ combo, second gapcloser in R
- *Zed*: Mobility through W , second gapcloser in R
- *Riven*: Mobility through Q and E
- *Renekton*: Less burst can 70%-0%, mobility through E
- *Kha'zix* : Mobility through E, Speedboost in R, high burst conditional extra damage
- *Lee Sin* : Can jump on enemies with Q, mobility trough W, high burst with R

**AP:**

- *Nidalee* : Mobility in cougar form with W
- *Leblanc* : Mobility through W, can replicate with R
- *Ekko* : Mobility through E, less burst

### Medium and Conditional Mobility:

These champions have their mobility tied to a condition, or can't use their mobility to bypass obstacles.

**AD:**

- *Talon*: Can jump on enemy with E, speed boost and stealth with R
- *Pantheon*: Can jump on enemy with W, major map movement with R
- *Rengar* : Can jump on enemy with passive, speed boost + passive + stealth with R
- *Wukong* : Can jump on enemies with E, minor speedboost with R

**AP:**

- *Akali*: Can jump on enemy with R 3 times
- *Katarina* : Can jump on enemies and allies with E
- *Ahri* : Can dash with R 3 times
- *Elise* : Spider-form E and Q, on enemies

The rest of the cast lacks any of the 2 conditions you describe, they may lack mobility but have burst or have mobility but not burst. Some may have bursty pattern but aren't meant for that except if fed beyond redemption then any character can be bursty.

I know there are champions that can speed themselves up but rarely are they real burst champions and more like sustained with some burst champions. I think this list caters to OP's question, champions that can get in fast and do their job of killing someone, with sometimes having a way out.

Comment: For clarity, why i don't add fiora,yi,nocturne,hecarim, altough they are high mobility champions with lots of movement speed,damage and reposition they aren't burst character, they are sustained fighters, they wither their enemies down , altough fast it doesn't compares to the ones i put in, its not the same to go in spell,spell,spell some auto kill, than, autoatacking someone to death, the first occurs in mere seconds, the second one needs "considerable" more time in comparison

Comment: Do you consider Yasuo a bursty champion? Cuz when he get's IE and Statik he can just kill anyone quickly if so, he can be added to the Conditional Mobility part

Comment: nocturne actually is a burst champion, he is considered and played has an assassin

Comment: I don't consider yasuo a burst champion, altough its true that he can kill quickly major part of his damage comes from the autoatacks, he needs a big setup time that reduces with higher atack speeds, think in yasuo in a yi with some CC and a big conditional mobility. a yi with the same setup can kill as quickly as yasuo but his damage is a bit more delayed. Both are considered asasins so they go into the described mobility + burst, but both are more in the sustained damage category

Comment: Then can we consider Graves and assassin? He only has his E for mobility but has really high burst

Comment: @Magmagod i think you are misunderstanding something, i am listing champions with a high burst damage and good mobility/repositioning not a specific class, graves is considred and adc , with realy high burst play pattern and some mobility with E and repositioning with R, yes we could include him in the list, i think op is looking for characters that don't need a lot of setup for the damage, most of the listed don't care if you run around they do their damage and once done have to wait before they can continue with it, staying with a subpar damage until theyr combo or part of it recovers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36502/discussion-between-xerido-and-magmagod).

Answer (score 0):

Clarification: I'm not posting here champs with high autoattack damage (Azir soldiers many marksmen, fiora, yi, etc) nor over-time damage (like Teemo's passive). Just the instant damage from abilities. Also I couldn't play every champion since rework, so if someone wants to add something about Graves, Poppy would be great.
Answers following this format: **Name** (lane): Burst / Movility / Score.

**Ahri** (mid lane):
   Her 4 damage abilities (including a cc with damage amplificator and a true damage skill) make her great for bursting.
   Also, with her ultimate she can dash three times to become a very movile champion.
   4/5 - Unless the target is squishy or she is really fed, hard to 100%-0% anyone.

**Akali** (mid/top lane):
   To be able to burst with Akali, you have first to hit the Q on the enemy, the plop damage of the passive is pretty high. Also, she has mixed damage (both magical and physical) making a tank build to her more difficult.
   For movility, her ultimate dash with a considerable range and her W grants her invisibility in the area where is casted.
   4/5 - If she has no target to ulti, or a pink ward is on, she loose movility.

**Caitlyn** (bot lane carry):
   Her remake gives her great damage with the passive. For making the best of this you should go for thunder masterie and the combo should be E + Q + AA (Auto Attack). The E + Q should be both clicked almost at the same time, it's a common Cait combo. With her passive, when you hit enemy with E you gain range to auto at him, so you are at a safe distance and the AA will trigger the masterie since E and Q would stack also and the 3rd stack would have more damage for the passive of Cait and the thunder masterie. And the ultimate, as always, greats lot of damage and massive range.
   Okey, so she is not a very movile champion, but at least she has the E to repositionate in a battle and gain some distance with a bruiser.
   3/5 - Althought she has burst, and her AA deals nice damage, the movility is not high.

**Corki** (bot/mid lane):
   His Q, ulti and passive gives him nice damage, and he has a lot of mixed damage (physical, magical and true with AA).
   With the W he can travel far, and even more with the new package, like from base to inhib or something like that.
   5-5 - Nice sustained damage and excelent movility, can't 100%-0% but from distance can leave an entire team bellow half healt in less than 15s.

**Fizz** (mid/top lane):
   With three damage abilities (and with nice damage), well timed combo can burst a not so squishy champ. With well timed I mean, in the moment the shark comes out, with W activated, Q + AA.
   One of the most movile champions, with his E you can pick betwwen double jump and juke jump (jump and go back to first place). And his passive ignores unit collision.
   5-5 - Even the burst is excelent, the movility is what grant Fizz the 5 score.

**Gangplank** (top lane):
   2 items, one hit anyone. Thats Gangplank with the rework, his barrell just does insane damage. Give him a Trinity and Infinity and he is the scariest champ in game.
   For movility, he is pretty fast and can cleanse after eating the orange.
   4/5 - Probably highest burst in the game, but low movility compared with other champs in this list.

**Kassadin** (mid lane):
   Stacking ulti he has good damage, full combo including AA with W activated can burst very well.
   One of most movile champions, he has a blink every 6s or so.
   4/5 - After combo he has to go out or Zhonyas as he is not very fast and has to wait for Cds.

**Katarina** (mid lane):
   She has good damage, her ulti is great, it's kind of tricky because it's not burst damage ultimate as it does damage per second, but anyway she is here, with 4 damage abilities.
   Her jump gives great movility and with her passive she can enter and exit fights pretty easily, also gains movement speed if hit enemy champion with W.
   4/5 - Her efectivness relies on killing a champion or getting an assist early in the fight, anyway... Movile and good damage.

**LeBlanc** (mid lane):
   Total beast in early game, can 100%-0% with almost any of her combos. For AoE burst Q + W + R. For single target burst Q + R. For CC chain Q + E + R. Always Q first to plop passive.
   Her W (and R if used W as last spell) makes her jump and gives the option to go back to the first place. Perfect for juking, chasing, running.
   5/5 - Incredibly good damage and movility.

**Rengar** (jungler):
   Jump into an enemy and Q him twice (with 4 and 5 stacks). That should kill him or get him low. Terror of ADC's with his ultimate.
   Can jump to any enemy from bush or with ulti, which also grants stealth and mov. speed.
   4/5 - Can only jump on enemies, excelent burst damage.

**Riven** (mid/top lane):
   A combo with 3rd Q + W + R can melt an entire team down. Also in 1v1 with stacking passive with abilities + AA it's hard to defeat her.
   A dash and three mini-jumps, with one of them able to go through some walls.
   4/5 - Even with low CD, she doesn't have a high range mobility.

**Talon** (mid lane):
   High base damage and burst with combo. His ulti added to his gapcloser and other abilities can 100%-0% almost every mid laner and ADC.
   A jump with decent range and his ulti with stealth and mov. speed make him pretty movile.
   4/5 - Lacks on movility when no enemies closer or running away if ulti is down.

**Yasuo** (mid lane):
   His passive gives him a lot of critical chance, so almost every Q should crit. Added to that, the Q + R combo will totally do tons of damage on enemies hit.
   Can dash through every enemy unit with almost no CD.
   4/5 - Another one that is no movile if no enemies to dash.

**Zed** (mid lane):
   Very high burst, a combo and ulti plop could get almost every champion.
   Very high movility using shadows to dance arround.
5/5 - Excelent burst and excelent movility to engage or disengage.

Answer (score -1):

## Disclaimer:

I will be listing champions for their **mobility** and not burst, i consider mobility has anything that gives you either increasing Movement Speed or something that allows you to move a Distance . **Without the use of Summoner Spells**.

So i will be classifying the champions by their "Standard Lane"(which means i won't say Fizz is a Top Laner, since he is considered a Mid Laner, although he works great on Top as well).

If by any chance i miss a champion, feel free to add it in, there are

## Top Lane

- Aatrox - Has a decent Escape tool/Gap closer with his Q (Dark Flight)
- Fiora - Has ridiculous ammounts of mobility due to her Q (Lunge) being on such a low Cooldown (this won't happen if you somehow miss the Q)
- Gnar - Has good mobility if you are able to prock your W (Hyper/Wallop) and has the E (Hop/Crunch) has an Escape Tool, does better VS meelee matchups since he is able to kite so well thanks to this kit.
- Jax - Has decent mobility due to his Q (Leap Strike) but it tends to be better on the later levels, where the cooldown is reduced.
- Irelia - Really good mobility but only around minions thanks to her Q (Bladesurge), if you kill a minion you get Q again, which allows you to jump around the whole lane.
- Renekton - One of the best champions for top lane regarding mobility (Personal opinion) , thanks to his E (Slice and Dice) you can jump in, win the trade, and jump back out.
- Riven - Has the highest mobility of all top laners, her Q and E allow her to just do whatever she wants in lane (Assuming you are a good riven player).
- Tryndamere - Decent mobility in the late game since his Crits reduce the cooldown on his E (Spinning Slash) which is his main mobility tool.
- Wukong - Has a good Gap Closer with his E (Nimbus Strike) and a good escape tool with his W (Decoy) if he is well played he can win most matchups on top lane.
- Malphite - Despite the looks, Malphite can be pretty mobile since he steals your Movement Speed with his Q (Seismic Shard) and has his R (Unstoppable Force) that, like the name suggests, makes him unstoppable.
- Poppy - Has a good Gap Closer with her E (Heroic Charge) and good Movement Speed buff from her W (Steadfast Presence), while her W can help you escape ganks, it needs levels before you start really noticing the difference in Movement Speed gained.
- Shen - Has his E (Shadow Dash) to serve has a Gap Closer/ Escape Tool, not a huge difference, but it's something.
- Nautilus - His Q gives him a decent enough Escape Tool (Since you can use it against walls).

## Jungle

- Amumu - Has a Q (Bandage Toss) that serves has a Gap Closer.
- Elise - Has an E (Cocoon/Rappel) that gives her a huge Gap Closer, and also gains additional Movement Speed while in Spider Form (some people don't know that).
- Evelynn - Although not a huge impact, she does have a W (Dark Frenzy) that removes all Slow effects from her and gives her a huge burst of speed.
- Fiddlesticks - Even if it's only his R (Crowstorm), worth noting that it does allow you to move in ways others wouldn't (Passing trough walls and big distances).
- Gragas - Has his E (Body Slam) to serve has a mobility tool and his R (Explosive Cask) that displaces enemies.
- Hecarim - Gains a huge burst of speed from his E (Devastating Charge) and his T (Onslaught of Shadows) is a Gap Closer/ Escape Tool.
- Jarvan IV - Huge Gap Closer with his E+Q combo (Demacian Standard + Dragon Strike).
- Kha'Zix - Doesn't have much mobility until you evolve his E (Leap) but once you evolve it you are one slippery bug!
- Kindred - One of the highest mobility junglers, with her Q (Dance of Arrows) cooldown being reduced by her W (Wolf's Frenzy).
- Lee Sin - Another one of the highest mobility junglers, his W (Safeguard / Iron Will) allows you to jump to everything allied, and your Q also allows you to pass trough walls and other terrain.
- Master Yi - Well, yeah, this champion. His Q (Alpha Strike) makes him untargetable and has a decent range, his R (Highlander) provides him a huge burst of speed. That's that enough of him.
- Nidalee - Another high mobility jungler, since i can't really understand her very well, i hope someone will edit this explaining her mobility skills.
- Nocturne - Decent Gap Closer with his R (Paranoia) and his Q (Duskbringer) gives him a bit of bonus Movement Speed.
- Pantheon - His W (Aegis of Zeonia) gives him a small Gap Closer and his R (Grand Skyfall AKA Mandrop) gives him a huge nearly global presence in the map.

### I know i am Still missing a few of them, but i have to get some sleep! Will finish it once i have time

## Mid Lane

## ADC (AD Carry)

## Support

Comment: This answer is the reason this question was put on hold in the first place. Lets try not to prove them right.

Comment: Not to mention that it doesn't even fit in the description of the answer, I count at least 10 Sustained Damage dealers here

Comment: In what way is nidalee mobile? Only mobile thing is the leap that brings you like half a foot forward...

Comment: I never said i would specify bursty champions, just mobility champions, and i also said i would specify any champion that has an advantage whether big or small in terms of "moving" around

Comment: You are simply listing any champion that can use a spell to move faster or go into position with no added benfit or burst pattern. most of what you put in are champions that want to get in and stay in because they dont have such high damage that they can simply delete someone upon arriving. @AshwinGupta nidalee is treated as mobile because she can jump over river ledges and her Little leap can be enormous if you leap to a marked champion

Comment: @AshwinGupta Actually, Nidalee is incredibly mobile. Her pounce can cross walls, has extended range against hunted targets, and has a relatively low cd (7s). In addition to that, she has increased ms when moving towards hunted targets and when traveling through brush.

Comment: @nukeforum oh okay I didn't realize that. Its been a while since I've played (Aatrox update was last time), so that may be new because I don't remember her being that mobile

Answer (score -2):

Akali is pretty good in both respects given her ridiculous damage and great mobility with her ult. Other than that, I hate to say it but Teemo may also be pretty good due to his W adding stupid mobility and with the right build he can deal massive amounts of damage.

Comment: depending on what your definition of mobile is, there can be a lot more champs classified as mobile. and if having movespeed is considered mobile, then anyone with ghost would be considered mobile

Comment: By mobile I mean, have abilities that let them have a movement advantage over other champions. Like Fizz's E and Wukong's W and Ahri's ult and even Ezreal's E. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Then whiteland you could put it in the question like "which champions have skill(s) to move faster or to jump in the map" etc

Answer (score -2):

off the top of my head (most will be mid cos I main mid)

Akali

ahri

leblanc

katarina

kassadin

ekko

fizz

talon

zed

yasuo

pantheon

nocturne

nidalee

corki

also if you are looking for high burst high mobility champions I suggest you play assassins in mid. Especially Leblanc, Ahri, Zed and Ekko