# Viable Non-Meta Junglers?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am looking for Champions that Jungle incredibly well even if they are not necessarily played often. Specifically looking for champions with fast wave clear and good early game ganks. Basically, I am looking for an underplayed Jungler who is still viable in Season 6. Thanks!

Comment: You really should stop putting "Best" in your question titles dude.

Comment: @nukeforum It's very well defined what Best means. In fact, your edit changed the author's intent as 'viable' does NOT mean 'best'. There are a lot of viable characters who are definetly not good. But they're viable

Comment: @Oak No, I didn't change the author's intent, because in the body of his question, he used the term viable. Which is what he meant all along. Anyway, if we leave the term "best" in the title, you can bet there will be another 3 day long discussion about whether the question should be closed or not and I want this guy to get answers.

Comment: @nukeforum I disagree because one thing is being viable (as in being able to jungle), and another is being viable as in gamewise. For example, Leona Jungle is able to waveclear decently, and has superb ganks. Is she a viable jungler however? Not really, because she lacks mobility and is outrotated rather easily against any half good team. Meaning while she is viable in the jungle she is not viable (aka: good) as a jungler.  The problem is that non-LoL users enforce non-LoL terms and as such end up forcing LoL questions to be removed due to ignorance / relutancy to be informed

Comment: @Oak I'm not a non-LoL user and your argument makes no sense. Viable means viable. If a champ doesn't have the ability to do at least 2 of the jungle tasks well, they aren't viable. Leona can't even make the first clear either healthy or fast and her clear speed does not improve. She's not viable.. No matter which viable you're considering.

Comment: @nukeforum I know you're not  a non-Lol user. Leona is surprisingly good clearer. The first clear is painfully slow, but not only she is fairly healthy when she finishes but she can actually clear relatively fast once she gets bami's Cinder or 3 points in the W or E. It's surprisingly good at staying in the jungle. It's just not effective and good compared to the current trend of fast(er) clears and strong(er) duelers

Comment: @Oak You can't have a painfully slow first clear or you'll get countered. There is nothing valuable about the discussion here. We're splitting hairs for no reason. Viable means viable. OP is looking for the "best" non-meta champions. If meta is x, y, and z, then anything non-meta that works well* is viable. *Don't go throwing Taric or Ziggs (or Leona) recommendations around, they work, but they're awful aka not viable.

Comment: @nukeforum The thing is that counter jungling can either be by forcing a fight (which Leona has no problems against), or clearing in front of her, which she does have a problem with, but she can engage on that and hve her team collapse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36797/discussion-between-nukeforum-and-oak).

Comment: "viable non-meta junglers" does seem like an oxymoron. If it works, it's part of the meta. If it doesn't, it's not.

Comment: @nukeforum I apologize. I had no intention of making arguments. I will work on making my questions realistic and not as confusing. And keep "best" out of my titles.

Comment: @WhiteLard There's no need to apologize. Just pay a bit more attention to the discussions occur on your questions. One of your previous questions (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256727/which-champions-specialize-in-burst-damage-and-high-mobility) sparked quite a lot of discussion, including [this meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11332/league-of-legends-questions-separating-opinion-from-meta-strategy-and-other-f). I personally have edited many of your questions, and I think you have good intentions, but I think that you should read some of the meta..

Comment: .. regarding League of Legends questions just to make sure you have a really solid grasp on what will be closed and what won't be. A second reading of the Arqade posting guidelines probably wouldn't be remiss either.

Comment: @user1337 Here's a quick differentiation of the two: Nunu is a viable off-meta jungler. 0.66% pick rate, 0.06% ban rate, 51.84% win rate. Obviously effective, just not part of the core meta currently. Xerath is a non-viable jungler. 0% jungle position pick rate. No effective clearing tools, no effective invading tools, low mobility, nearly no ganking pressure. This is the distinction between a non-meta jungler and a non-viable jungler.

Comment: @nukeforum I appreciate it very much and thanks a lot. I will work on that for sure. Again, Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any. Out of the few junglers that fit the *fast wave clear and good early game ganks* archtype, there is not a single jungler that is underplayed right now.

It can be argued that Trundle and Skarner (who have fast clears) are underplayed (1% and 1.29% pick rate respectively) but their ganks are situational and are not particularly considered strong early gankeds per League's Standarts.

Xin Zhao, Volibear, Amumu and Udyr are currently strong clearers with strong ganks early on, but they are indeed popular (5-8% pick rate in the jungle) and as such they are out of scope of the answer.

(It's worth mentioning that 5% pick rate is considered popular in the context of Ranked Summoner's Rift - Where each player plays a total of 10% of the involved Champions in the game as as such 5% pick rate is a good indicator of a champion's popularity )

Comment: Since there is huge amount of people playing, analyzing, and even deliberately practicing for this game, plus the enticement of monetary rewards, it is extremely unlikely to "discover" a hidden champion that is better and is also underplayed.  People will exhaust all possibilities to maximize their winning potential.

Comment: It's not necessarly hard, as it's rather easy to just sort down the list of junglers by playrate

Comment: Tryndamere, Vi, Elise? All have good clear and solid ganks idk what their pick %'s are.

Comment: 4% Jungle Pick Rate on Vi, 9.8% on Elise. Both are played quite a lot. Tryndamere ganks are situational at best

Comment: You forgot master yi and shyvana...

Comment: This answer isn't based on opinions, but on statistics and facts. Both Shyvana and Yi are NOT strong gankers. Their ganks can be strong provided certain scenarios, such as the opponent not having any escapes and being pushed, or your laner having enough CC and Damage to hold him back if you manage to surprise him. They are /bad/ early gankers due to being both melee without Crowd Control and bad / weak gapclosers

Comment: Your final note on pick rates is flawed- pick rates say % of games which include that champion, *not* % of champions played which are this champ. If Udyr is picked every game, he has a 100% pick rate, not 10%.